# How to get RSS feeds from other sites and display their links in a block?

Tags: feeds

I am using the aggregator core module, I also have feeds module installed but I can't figure how to make it read a remote rss and display the remote links in a block.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6, Views-6.x-2.12 has built-in Aggregator type you can configure. Make sure you have contents in your aggregator from a valid RSS Feed.